# Changing the ConnectionString in Entity Framework 4

Tags: database-connection, entity-framework-4

I'm working on updating an old system, and we're introducing Entity Framework for some new functionality. The system is, however, too large to do the migration in one step, so I would like to do some testing in another database before updating the db schema.

I have created an empty model, included a couple of tables from the database, and added a couple of new entities from scratch, along with relationships between these entities and the old tables. Now I want to create a new database schema in another database with my desing model, but I can't figure out how to switch so that clicking "Update database from model..." won't work with the old database, but the with the new one.

Is there a straight-forward way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In short, the connection settings are in your config file or a Data Connection. [Entity Framework Connections and Models](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592674) provides official documentation.

If your connection settings are in your config file, i.e. Web.config / App.config, you can change them there (additional documentation available in [Entity Framework Config File Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606)). If you used EF Designer to create your model, the option to save settings in the config file was in the [Choose Your Data Connection Dialog Box (Generate Database Wizard)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456811%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

If your connection settings aren't in a config file, they live in the Data Connection in the Server Explorer in Visual Studio: View > Server Explorer; expand Data Connections, right-click on the connection and choose Modify Connection.